# How should I format a string when passing multiple arguments to Process.Start when part of the string is a var

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass 2 arguments to the Process.start in  c# and part of the string has to be a string var that is built from the input of the user.

This code works fine when I use a simple folder path but my path is determined by the user to the `process.StartInfo.Arguments must = "-format mp4 -outfolder " + myVar`.

I cannot get this to work.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\NCH Software\Prism\Prism.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-format mp4 -outfolder C:/users/john";
process.Start();
```

The expected results would be the prism opening screen having the mp4 format automatically selected (which works fine) and the output folder is set by the variable. that part of the argument is being ignored and a default folder is being set up.

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: Please also show a call that you have successfully used from a command prompt that **does work** (and has a folder in the path). Then we can work backwards to identify how to generate that from C#.

Comment: Also be clear what OS this is running on.

Comment: Just add quotes around the path parameter.

Comment: sorry mjwillis i got busy and am just getting back into this. it is windows 10 and the command prompt that works is: C:\path to prism\prism.exe -format mp4  -outfolder C:\path of folder..

Comment: @jlmiscad `C:\path of folder` Please show us an **actual value that works** - don't describe it, show an actual path.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NCH Software\Prism\prism.exe" -format mp4 -outfolder "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Henry 24 Jun 2019\mp4"   This is the code that works

Comment: Compare the string that works and the one that doesn't. Note that the slash is different and that your working one has quotes around the path and the non-working one doesn't.

Comment: Yes but that is the problem. The path to the out folder must be a variable rather than a literal string and I cannot figure out how to create the argument so it is read properly.' In other words the "-outfolder" is a constant but the path must be appended to it and that is what i cannot figure out. by the way thanks for sticking with me on this one. I don't explain things as well as I should.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `myVar`?

Comment: Directory.CreateDirectory(myVar); This is the code used to create the desired directory using myVar. The path to this directory is: C:\Users\John\Desktop\Henry 24 Jun 2019\mp4. That all works fine. Then I need to add that directory to "-outfolder" to end up with this "-outfolder C:\Users\John\Desktop\Henry 24 Jun 2019\mp4". and that is the problem. no matter what I have tried it will not work as I think it should. I can type in the literal string that I need and it works but when I try to combine the literal string "-outfolder" with the myVar that is used to create the directory it fails.

Comment: When you checked the value of `myVar` in the `Immediate Window` or `Debug Window` what was its value?

Comment: Ok after more testing and following your suggestion I have found that it is the spaces within path that are not being handled as I would expect. I append the name that is input with a date (Henry 24 Jun 2019) and the outfolder path ends at the first space. it works in the command line because it is in quotes but does not work with the variable input when there are spaces.

Comment: If anyone has any further suggestions I would love to hear them but I have solved my problem by putting a "_" anywhere I would use a space. It provides separation for readability and can still be used in the arguments. Thanks for your help and sorry about my not being able to explain the problem adequately.

Comment: All you need to do is add quotes. If you could share the value of `myVar` I can show you how.

Comment: "C:\\users\\john\\desktop\\Henry 26 Jun 2019\\MP4" This is the value of myVar.I have changed it now to: "C:\\users\\john\\desktop\\Henry_26_Jun_2019\\MP4"  and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you have to use \" \" between the var.

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-format mp4 -outfolder  @\" " + myVar + "\""
```

Follow this site and you can find more information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=netframework-4.8

or else try,

```
 string a = "aaa";
 string b = "bbb";
 Process.Start(@"something.exe ", "@"+ a + " " + b );
```

Comment: Sorry no go. I can see what is being tried here with the first answer and it looks like it should work. I pasted it as is into my code and added the semi-colon at the end but it still does not recognize the second parameter. As for the second suggestion I still cannot see how to combine the literal string and myVar to make it work. Thanks for the link to Docs but that did not help either.

Comment: I actually have done this and it works for me. But it was just a plain string not a path. maybe you can try putting @ before path. I edited the original answer.